# how to print out the following value using printf in C?

Tags: c, printf

I have a variable:

```
int a = 0x0304;
```

I print it out like this:

```
printf("the value is 0x4x\n", a);
```

but it shows the value is `0x304,` I want the result should be the value is `0x0304`, how to print it out like this?

Comment: have you read the man page for printf?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding a leading `0` to your format specifier - `%04x`

```
printf("the value is 0x%04x\n", a);
```

Just in case its omission from your question wasn't a typo, note that I've also added a `%` to make this a format specifier.  As it stands, the code in your question would have just echoed `the value is 0x4x`